# Ambiguous Layout - What Additional Constraint(s) Do I Need to Add for Two Side by Side Views?

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view that slides down from the navigation bar - allowing the user to change the title name. I'm using auto layout, programatically.

**What I'm aiming for**: the label takes up as much horizontal space as it needs (e.g. change due to localisation), and it pinned to the left of its super view (with a margin). The text field takes up the rest of the space, regardless of its content (and has a margin between it and the label, and a margin on the right).

**The problem**: both the `UILabel` and the `UITextField` have ambiguous layout. Unless my constraints are plain wrong, I need to add additional constraints... I'm just not sure what to add. I've tried `setContentCompressionResistancePriority` and `setContentHuggingPriority` on the horizontal access, but haven't gotten that to work.

What am I missing?

**The following images are with no *Hugging* or *Compression* priorities in place, as per the code below**.

How it should look, all the time:
[image]

Edit to short name can cause this:
[image]

Edit to a long name can cause this:
[image]

Here's the code:

```
_renameView = [UIView new];
_renameView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_renameView.backgroundColor = _styles.navbarLightGreyTrans;
[self.view addSubview:_renameView];

_renameTextField = [UITextField new];
_renameTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_renameTextField.delegate = self;
_renameTextField.clipsToBounds = YES;
_renameTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_renameTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
_renameTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.7f;
_renameTextField.layer.borderColor = [_styles.greyBorder CGColor];
_renameTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
[_renameTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
[_renameView addSubview:_renameTextField];

UIView* separator = [UIView new];
separator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
separator.backgroundColor = _styles.greyBorder;
[_renameView addSubview:separator];

UILabel* label = [UILabel new];
label.text = @"Name:";
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[_renameView addSubview:label];
```

Constraints:

```
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_renameView]|"
               options:0
               metrics:nil
               views:views];

[self.view addConstraints:constraints];

constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[separator]|"
               options:0
               metrics:nil
               views:views];

[_renameView addConstraints:constraints];

constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[label]-[_renameTextField]-10-|"
               options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
               metrics:nil
               views:views];

[_renameView addConstraints:constraints];

constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-7-[_renameTextField(==36)]-7-[separator(==0.72)]|"
               options:0
               metrics:nil
               views:views];

[_renameView addConstraints:constraints];
```

**Update**

Log of the ambiguous layout:

```
|   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x10c57d710>
|   |   |   |   |   |   *<UITextField:0x10c57d990> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIFieldEditor:0x10c60a150>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <_UIFieldEditorContentView:0x10c60a710>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UITextSelectionView:0x10c038850>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x10c034730>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x10c60f790>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x10c60fad0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x10c582620>
|   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x10c582700>
|   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x10c5827e0> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   |   |   |   *<_UILayoutGuide:0x10c582b50> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
```

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of space on the horizontal axis between the label and the text field is ambiguous. Try setting the content hugging priority for the label. I omitted the vertical constraints.

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[label]-[textField]-|"
                                                              options:0
                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                views:viewsDictionary]];

[label setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
[label setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

Comment: I've updated my question to show what's being reported as ambiguous - it's the `UILabel` and `UITextField`. Setting the content Hugging Priority does actually remove the ambiguous report - *until* a type a super long string in the textfield, after which, if I hide and re-show it, the ambiguous layout returns.

Comment: You are right, the text field can squash the label, if its content gets long. I updated my answer to keep this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the ambiguous layout by fixing the width of the `UILabel`.

```
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[label(==50)]-[_renameTextField]-10-|"
               options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
               metrics:nil
               views:views];

[_renameView addConstraints:constraints];
```

This works, regardless of how long or short the content is, in the `UITextField`. Of course, I've had to hard-code the width of the label, which is what I was trying to avoid...

[image]

Comment: See @rshog’s answer. By setting the content hugging priority of the label, it should always be the exact right size, even if the text changes.